# Include WP header and footer in website but problem with styles and scripts

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So basically I am trying to include Wordpress footer and header to another non Wordpress site..

I am testing with the following code:

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');
get_header(); 
get_footer();
```

I loads the header and the footer, but some styles and scripts are missing - like there are no colors to the menu or mobile menu doesn't expand.

There are no errors in the console.. There are no other scripts and styles with the code I am testing..

Any suggestions how to fix it or what could be wrong?

Comment: Those styles and scripts might get added by a plugin, and I don't think simply embedding wp-load executes any of those ...

Comment: `get_header` and `get_footer` don't add any scripts by themselves. You need `wp_head()` and `wp_foot()` for that.

Comment: wp_foot() is not working.. Maybe I should require other file? It is same with wp_head().